# Flutter, Dart - Trying to parse images from a webiste and failing

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing

I am trying to parse data from an online store and instead of getting image urls am getting '/static/platform/frontend/assets/app/image-placeholder.svg'. Parsing works correctly otherwise.

[image]

The error message:

[image]

Have been trying to parse data from arbuz.kz.

I've tried to parse the same data from other online stores and web sites, didn't result in any change.

Here's my code: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:xleb/data/article.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List<Article> articles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    getWebsiteData();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future getWebsiteData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://arbuz.kz/ru/collections/249615-pozabottes_o_sebe_#/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    dom.Document html = dom.Document.html(response.body);

    final titles = html
        .querySelectorAll(' article > main > a')
        .map((e) => e.innerHtml.trim())
        .toList();
    final prices =
        html.querySelectorAll('b').map((e) => e.innerHtml.trim()).toList();

    final urlImages =
        html.querySelectorAll('img').map((e) => e.attributes['src']!).toList();
    print(urlImages);
    print(titles);

    setState(() {
      articles = List.generate(
        titles.length,
        (index) => Article(
          title: titles[index],
          price: prices[index],
          urlImage: urlImages[index],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: articles.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final article = articles[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(article.title),
                subtitle: Text(article.price),
                leading:
                    SizedBox(width: 50, child: Image.network(article.urlImage)),
              );
            }));
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Provided! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I think you getting the placeholder image because all the images are lazy loaded.. You will have to find some other way to do web scraping

Comment: Could you specify how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the website was using lazy loading. Twisted my code a bit and it works perfectly now. Changes I've made:

```
  final urlImages = html
    .querySelectorAll('a.product-card__link > img')
    .map((e) => e.attributes['v-lazy']!.replaceAll("'", ''))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the host (`https://arbuz.kz/`, in this case) before the image URLs. You can do it like this:

```
Article(
  title: titles[index],
  price: prices[index],
  urlImage: 'https://arbuz.kz${urlImages[index]'},
),
```

Comment: Does not fix the main issue, being unable to parse image urls correctly

Comment: The HTML is parsed correctly, you can see one of the element from the raw HTML is like this: `<img src="/static/platform/frontend/assets/banners/store_main.svg" alt="Arbuz logo" width="220">`. There is no host URL in the element `src`, you have to put it yourself

Comment: Other sites may include host URL on their images, but this arbuz.kz site doesn't. The reason why it works is because the URLs are being referred from the site itself. You are trying to refer to the URL from outside the site (which is your app), so you need to put host URL manually

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the image's extension, especially when using '.svg' as the image URL. Use [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package.

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/logo.svg', // Replace with your SVG file's asset path
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use mime svg you need to use the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package.
If you use this package but it doesn't work and you get an error again, maybe it's because of the backend and the image address.
This is from the ssl certificate that the backend needs to set.
(This happens more on the web than any other platform)